# Implementing Authorization using keycloak, after extracting the RPT token how to map the Resource Name with the controllers and unauthorize a user

Tags: java, playframework, authorization, keycloak

I am working on a Play Framework Rest API, which uses keycloak for authentication and now on extending towards the authorization, i have extracted the RPT token and stored the permission access based on resource name. But now i have no idea how to map my controllers with the resource name and restrict the user to use certain functions which can only be used by admin or a different role. The structure of permission is:

```
"authorization": {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "rsid": "4bxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
        "rsname": "Default Resource"
      },
      {
        "rsid": "8xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
        "rsname": "admin_res"
      },
      {
        "rsid": "cxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
        "rsname": "superAdmin_res"
      }
    ]
  },
```

And i am storing all the rsname in a list and stored locally in the session.

Now i just want to control the api calls based on resource name and restricting the controller calls.

I have a KeyCloakSessionAction which extends to a action.simple, so how can i pass the auth details along with it and restrict certain controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much better solution to this using, Custom Annotation which will restrict a particular API if the user does not have access to those resources.

Kindly refer here: https://www.javatpoint.com/custom-annotation

And based on that you can set the value as the resource name and check every time a user calls an API.

> For eg. @Authorization(Default Resource) over

```
@Authorization(Default Resource)
public class getPassword(){
...
...
...
}
```

Add this line Before every API Call. Here only the users with Default Resource in their session will be allow to successfully fetch the password.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if are using any keycloak adaptor, if your are implementing one for playframework, you need not store permissions, you can directly get overall decision from token end point some thing like this

```
curl -X POST 
  http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token 
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" 
  --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" 
  --data "audience={resource_server_client_id}" 
  --data "permission=Resource A#Scope A" 
  --data "response_mode=decision"
```

Response will be

```
 {
   'result': true
  }
```

you can more details form keycloak [documentation](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/57bae71a7503fb3e9fc0690fa836566bb21c59e5/authorization_services/topics/service-authorization-obtaining-permission.adoc)